# Help with understanding usage of Value Objects in Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3, object, value-objects

I have some small problem in understanding Value Objects in Flex... I'm trying to get some data from PHP/MySQL and send it to Flex but I'm stuck in some (obviously) basic problems...

Let's say That my object in Flex would look like this:

```
package some.package.VO {

    [RemoteClass(alias="VOPerson")]

    [Bindable]
    public class VOPerson {
        public var personID:int;
        public var firstName:String;
        public var lastName:String;
        public var personDetails:Array;
    }
}
```

In my case, `personDetails` is an Array, and in theory, it could be some other object... But is it really necessary to make it an `object`? I do not intend to use that data nowhere else except within my `VOPerson` class. It is some associative array, and I can easily transform it to another object, but there will be lots of similar situations in my app, so I would like to avoid making unnecessary (value) objects if there is no need for it...

Anyway, any tip/hint/link about my problem would be really appreciated! :)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not as familiar with PHP/Flex serialization as I am with Java/Flex, but I believe the same principles will hold.  If `personDetails` is an array of primitives, it will be serialized as such by Flex.  If `personDetails` is a type that Flex does not know how to serialize (i.e. you haven't defined it as a RemoteClass), it will be converted to an anonymous object.

If you're trying to prevent `personDetails` in your PHP code from being serialized to Flex in the first place, that might be more tricky.  I know that Flex identifies serializable fields in Java by looking for a public getter/setter pair, so you can prevent serialization by simply not exposing a getter and setter.  There might be some similar trick you can do in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for this great info! Just to ask, is there a need to serialize personDetails in my example, or is it OK to go with primitives? As I mentioned, personDetails is nothing else but simple associative array and it would be used only as a part of a person class, I won't use it as a separate class/object... Thanks!

Comment: The only advantage to putting personDetails in its own class would be if you want to add instance methods to it or pass it as a typed parameter to a method.  If you don't need this functionality, keeping it as an array of primitives would be less work.